# how to avoid deploying a branch into the production server?

Tags: version-control, deployment, maven

we're working with feature branches.

we're using a bash script to deploy, and that script has a parameter defining where to deploy: prod_server, test_env, local_virtualbox, etc.

however, feature branches and the trunk should always be deployed only to local/test and the previous stable version branch should be the only one that can be deployed to the prod env. (the only reason I'm asking is of course that recently I almost accidentally overwritten our prod with some feature branch).

Is there a nice way to do this? am I missing some maven proper approach to this problem, or should I just use some bashisms to check which branch am I working on and restrict according to the name of the env given in the parameter? should I be deploying only tags instead of branches?

(not sure that it's relevant but: java console application, spring shop, maven used for building).

Answer (score 1):

To solve this with version control alone:
You could prevent this if you write a build bash script that does a `svn co` on the trunk or the newest tag and executes the maven build on this fresh checkout.

If you want to use maven in the process as well:
I recommend that you place a check in your deploy bash script anyway to ensure that if you make a mistake somewhere that the last point of control will catch it.

In the projects I worked on with maven we designed the productive part as a profile. As the prod profile was the only one to contain the information necessary for deployment (and a final name that made it obvious for every one on the first look) it was impossible to deploy a non-productive version to the productive environment, but I don't think that applies to you (because you stated that you use branches and not profiles for feature development).

So, set the finalName like this in the productive profile and check for it in the deploy bash script and you should be fine:

```
<profile>
    <id>productive</id>
    <build>
        <finalName>MyProgram-productive-${version}</finalName>
    </build>
</profile>
```

That way you always have to manually apply the 'this is productive' flag to whatever you are building.

BUT this wont prevent you to set the 'this is productive' flag on a feature branch, because maven is not aware of its version control situation.